# Similar route in group of route with different guard in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I defined two different guard in `auth.php` file like this :

```
'guards' => [
            'web' => [
                'driver'   => 'session',
                'provider' => 'users',
            ],
            'website' => [
                'driver'   => 'session',
                'provider' => 'websites',
            ]
]
```

There is two different section routes in web.php routes. one for **website** admn and another for **normal users** that is a member of those websites. like this :

```
Route::prefix('/website/{website}')->middleware('auth:website')->group(function () {

            Route::group(['prefix' => 'banner_ads'], function () {
                Route::get('banner_adsDatatable', ['as' => 'banner_adsDatatable', 'uses' => 'BannerAdsController@banner_adsDatatable']);
            });
            Route::resource('/banner_ads', 'BannerAdsController');

     Route::prefix('/member/{member}')->middleware('auth:web')->group(function () {

            Route::group(['prefix' => 'banner_ads'], function () {
                Route::get('banner_adsDatatable', ['as' => 'banner_adsDatatable', 'uses' => 'BannerAdsController@banner_adsDatatable']);
            });
            Route::resource('/banner_ads', 'BannerAdsController');

     });
});
```

Problem is that I have a resource controller (banner ads) that is shared with to users (website admins and members). As you can see I must to add it twice time.

But beacause for normal user I defined `banner ads` controller again, when I call `banner_ads.update`  for example always return `unAuthenticated user`.

I do not know what can I do for solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `auth:web` middleware is inside `auth:website`. This is basically checking for an authenticated admin who is trying to access routes of an authenticated user.

You are trying to access routes as a normal user. So it is not working. Just replace your code with this:

```
Route::prefix('/website/{website}')->middleware('auth:website')->group(function () {

                    Route::group(['prefix' => 'banner_ads'], function () {
                        Route::get('banner_adsDatatable', ['as' => 'banner_adsDatatable', 'uses' => 'BannerAdsController@banner_adsDatatable']);
                    });
                    Route::resource('/banner_ads', 'BannerAdsController');

    });

Route::prefix('/member/{member}')->middleware('auth:web')->group(function () {



           Route::group(['prefix' => 'banner_ads'], function () {
                        Route::get('banner_adsDatatable', ['as' => 'banner_adsDatatable', 'uses' => 'BannerAdsController@banner_adsDatatable']);
                    });
                    Route::resource('/banner_ads', 'BannerAdsController');

             });
```

Comment: But `/member/{member}` should be a sub set of website directory

Comment: have you any idea?